# Possible number of outcomes in a round robin tournament vs possible number of pairings in a chess tournament

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

A round-robin tournament is being held with n tennis players; this means that every
player will play against every other player exactly once.
(a) How many possible outcomes are there for the tournament (the outcome lists out
who won and who lost for each game)?

This answer is $2^{\binom n2}$, because there are $\binom n2$ pairs and 2 outcomes per game, so using the multiplication rule it is $2^{\binom n2}$.

There are 20 people at a chess club on a certain day. They each  find opponents and
start playing. How many possibilities are there for how they are matched up, assuming
that in each game it does matter who has the white pieces (in a chess game, one player
has the white pieces and the other player has the black pieces)?

This answer is $\binom{20}{10}\cdot10! = \frac{20!}{ 10!}$, because we can first choose 10 people to get white chess pieces, fix their positions. And permute the remaining 10 players to the 10 positions.

My question is, isn't the second question extremely similar to the 1st question, why is the answer not $2^{\binom{20}2}$?

Comment: There are 2 BIG differences between your 2 exercices. In Chess example, they play only  1 round, not 19 rounds, as Ross explained. The other difference is that in one Game in Chess, game A against B, we note 2 informations, which player had the White pieces, and which player has won the game. We can even say there is a 3rd big difference, because in chess-game, it is possible that no player win a game, and the result is a draw. So, for each game  of chess, you have 6 different values, instead of 2 for tennis.

Answer (score 1):

In the tennis tournament there are ${20 \choose 2}=190$ games played.  In the chess club there are only $10$ games played.  Why should the number of possibilities be similar?